# Sizes of datatypes for actionscript 3

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, types

Anyone know any good resources or personal experience that help explain how much memory (and swf size) the various built-in data types take up in actionscript 3? I'm specifically interested in `int`, `Number`, and (dense) `Array`s or `Vector`s.

I'm working on a project where I need to embed large amounts of structured array data, which is already in C++ format, so porting is just a matter of copy-paste, search-replace.

I've already had a look at [Adobe's lowdown on datatypes](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/main/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=LiveDocs_Parts&file=00000047.html) but it's not specific enough, and doesn't mention Arrays, etc.

Comment: A strange things about Flash is that Numbers and Vectors seem to get the best performance.

Comment: @Todd: get outta town! Can you back that up with a link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this mobile development whitepaper for AS3. It's labelled as a "mobile" development spec, but the principles in here work for any Flash project.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/mobile/index.html

You can also experiment with the flash.sampler.getSize() method. A direct link to what you're looking at is here:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/mobile/WS4bebcd66a74275c3-576ba64d124318d7189-7fff.html
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/mobile/WS4bebcd66a74275c3a0f5f19124318fc87b-7fff.html

Comment: This was more or less what I was looking for - it's a lot like the sizeof operator in C. Maybe I coulda put that in the question.

Answer (score 3):

This SWF spec sheet may be what you are after http://www.adobe.com/devnet/swf/pdf/swf_file_format_spec_v9.pdf specifically Chapter 5.

Comment: Indeed, only found it a few months ago, its existance seems relatively unknown.

Comment: There is also an updated version http://www.adobe.com/devnet/swf/pdf/swf_file_format_spec_v10.pdf

Comment: nice one, you might have some more printing todo Todd :P

Comment: Ah brilliant, totally forgot about that one. Thanks Allan!

Answer (score 2):

Not really about the size of the datatypes, but rather details  about numeric types in AS3:
http://www.gskinner.com/blog/archives/2006/06/types_in_as3_in.html

Answer (score 2):

Not directly about datatype sizes in ActionScript, but it is a lot about memory and performance from one of the masters.

Check out [Grant Skinner's Quick as a Flash Presentation](http://www.gskinner.com/talks/quick/#73).  One of the best.

Comment: That is a nice presentation. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I came to the same question and wrote this flash.sampler thing. Here are code and results (scroll down):

http://www.flashforum.de/forum/actionscript-3/verwendeter-speicher-fuer-deklaration-va-initialisierung-288349.html